# Run Python script on windows from .py file in Latest Version Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning `Python` now.
At my very first program I am getting following error.

```
>>> python first_tutorial.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python first_tutorial.py
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Below is my code in that file -

```
name = "John"
age = 19 
print name
print age
```

I am using following `Python 3.5.1` version on `Windows 10`

I can print simple text from cmd line but no able to run script from file.

### Update

I am running it from command line itself.. first I make a folder on my docs then run cmd line and type `python` after that when I just type `print "Hello"` it works fine but when I run python file like `python first_tutorial.py` it shows error

Any guidance please.

Thanks

Comment: Just a nitpicking but `first_tutorial.py` and `firsttutorial.py` seems to be a little different. Anyway, more seriously, have you set the path of the Python interpreter?

Comment: Oh sorry thats my typo error.

Comment: Its not duplicate of that question. May be question is same but those answer not solved my problem.

Comment: It is a duplicate. The `>>>` arrows show you are trying to run python from python, not the command python

Comment: @John: I would expect that if you followed those answers, you would then get a SyntaxError at `print name` rather than `python first_tutorial.py`.  That means that your current problem is solved.  The `print name` is a separate problem.  To fix that, use `print(name)`.  Likewise, `print(age)`.

Comment: Thanks  zondo  cricket_007 ASCIIThenANSI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running in the Python interactive shell. It's trying to interpret your command as Python code, which causes an error.

You need to run `python first_tutorial.py` from the commandline. After that your code should work fine, assuming there's no other errors.

Comment: I am running it from commandline itself.. first I make a folder on my docs then run cmd line and type `python` after that when I just type `print "Hello"  ` it works fine but when I run python file like `python first_tutorial.py` it shows error

Comment: Yes you are correct. I was running after entering in Python interactive shell. But still Can I run file inside python shell. ?

Comment: John, if your script is named `mytest.py`, you can run it (once) from the interactive prompt with `import mytest`. But it's better to edit it in IDLE and run it with F5.

Answer (score 0):

When you type 'python' on the command prompt, you get an interpreter, so you can enter python code here:

```
>>> name = "john"
>>> print(name)
john
```

If you have a file `test.py` that you want to run, you can do that from the windows command prompt:

```
C:\Apps>python test.py
John
19
```

If you really want to run a python file from the python interpreter, you can do that too, but you need to open the file in python and `exec` it.

```
>>> with open("test.py") as f:
...   exec(f)
...
John
19
```

Comment: The third part is poor advice *and* incorrect (try it).